# How to disable linking double-precision libraries in GCC

Tags: gcc

I'm building an application for a small cortex M0 MCU and noticed that I'm losing ~10k of flash to double precision libs such as _strtod_l, __aeabi_dsub, __aeabi_dadd, etc. As far as I know, there is no double math being done but obviously something is requiring it.

I am trying to reduce code size, and have done a number of optimizations already and this seems like the last remaining low hanging fruit/outlier. I'm looking for some help with how best to track down why these are linked and see if I can eliminate them to free up valuable flash.

Note:

- -Wdouble-promotion does not report any warnings
- I've tried to append an 'f' to all fp literals, but I've also enabled -fsingle-precision-constant
- -fdata-sections, -ffunction-sections, -Wl, --gc-sections are all being used
- --specs=nano.specs
- Compiler is GNU Tools for STM32 (10.3-2021-10) included in CubeIDE

Comment: Do you want to _specifically_ not link double-precision libraries, or do you want to reduce the size of the executable? Is this XY problem? Do you use `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,gc-sections`? `GNU Tools for STM32` Are you using nano.specs / newlib nano version? What exact all compiler options are you using? Can you post a full [MCVE]?

Comment: I am trying to reduce code size, have done a number of optimizations already and this seems like the last possible low hanging fruit/outlier. Unfortunately I cannot share the sources, and part of the problem is that it's quite a large application. I will start pulling stuff out to try to trace what's pulling in these libs, but was hoping for a more methodical approach. I've updated my post with some additional details

Comment: If a "hello world" program doesn't pull in those floating point routines, try running `nm` on your objects/libraries and see which one is responsible.

Comment: I see the __aeabi_d* libraries in my map file but no references in the .o files. In the object files I only see __aeabi_f* libs being used. Should I be searching for something different or am I misinterpreting the double precision libs in my map file maybe?